# Eclipse : Can't import class from another project's test folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two projects, lets call them `A` and `B`. `B` is a dependency in `A`'s pom as

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

now i have some unit tests under `src/test/java/` in project `A`. Here is a test class i have

`src/test/java/packA/testForA.java`

Also, in project `B`, I have

`src/test/java/packB/configForB.java`

I need to import `configForB.java` from project `B`, into `testForA.java` in project `A`. When I try to do this, I get a

```
Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /path/to/project/A/src/test/java/packA/testForA.java:[18,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class configForB
[ERROR] location: package packB
```

why cant i import `configForB` ?

Comment: See maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) on how to do this.

Comment: thanks, that was it! thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but in Project B you need this in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>testJar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then in project A you need this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.projectb</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectbartifactid</artifactId>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Source: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a maven install to project B?
I had the same problem, and after I did a maven install it worked.

Comment: Try updating the dependencies. With Maven->Update Project.